# Differentiation of a function with 2 variables

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have a function:

$$
f: R^2 \to R
$$

Which satisfies:

$$
x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0, \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2
$$

Now the answers get in the end to:

[image]

How did they conclude that the right side sums to zero? I assume that it stems from the fact in the conditions of the question that:

$$
x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0, \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2
$$

But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in the question can be written as
$$x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x,y) + y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x,y) = 0 \textrm{ for any } (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2,$$
so, apply this with $(x,y) = (cx_0,cy_0)$.

Comment: +1. In addition, $f(0,0) = 0$ from the similar substitution.